# How to target Social Sharing button (Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn) groups using CSS?

Tags: css, button, display

I currently am styling my social sharing buttons using groupings (all Facebook buttons have a set style, all Twitter buttons do, etc.). Currently, I achieve this using a massive grouping of YUI's for each button type - this makes creating new sharing buttons extremely tedious, as I have to inspect each button to find its ID. Below is the code that stylizes my Facebook share buttons. The format is identical for my other button types, just with different YUIs - woefully lengthy. However, my code is functional as is:

```
#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1486492076694_136568, #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1486492076694_229456, #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1486492076694_301518, #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1486492076694_346464, #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1486492076694_390386, #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1486497764071_38998, #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1486497764071_84939, #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1486497764071_127888, #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1486497764071_167750, #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1486497764071_210706, #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1486762828716_16671, #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1487613145787_165402, #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1488578082993_168899, #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1489175439402_256947, #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1489873739917_158023, #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1490053051323_201623, #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1490837162453_152647, #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1491429139219_249912, #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1491948942477_176351 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to target each button type using their respective classes to REALLY consolidate the amount of code I have written (and make future additions much more efficient). I've tried everything I could think of, but nothing seems to work.

I'm currently working on the Squarespace platform.

Comment: You are going to have to post some code examples. What is it that is not working for you?

Comment: Yes what is your code? Post it here for better help.

Comment: Updated! My code is working, but it seems like there should be a much shorter way to write this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be because of Squarespace's default styles. When targeting elements, CSS prefers the more precise selector:

```
.social-icon {
  background-color: red;
  /* Less preferred */
}

html body div.social-area img.social-icon {
  background-color: blue;
  /* More preferred */
}
```

You can override this by using `!important`:

```
.social-icon {
  background-color: red !important;
  /* More preferred */
}

html body div.social-area img.social-icon {
  background-color: blue;
  /* Less preferred */
}
```

so when you style your social icons, use `!important` to override Squarespace's default styles.

```
.social-icon {
    display: inline-block !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey @Ori Marash - Thank you for your reply. I tried putting in the code and it had no effect. Actually, to clear up any confusion - the buttons are not supplied by Squarespace. They are HTML buttons (with the exception of LinkedIn, which is JS) that reside within code blocks, the code supplied by each service's developer sites. Therefore, each has a unique class applied to them, not one associated with Squarespace. I guess I just haven't found the correct class for each button type.

Comment: @TCharb The different button classes don't really matter. If the buttons have a common class in addition to their other classes (add a space between each class name to give multiple classes `class="class1 class2`) you can select all the buttons in your CSS and style them however you wish. So just add your custom class to all of the social buttons and style them.

Comment: For example, would something similar to this be written: 

`class1="fb-share-button click-share"`
`class2="twitter-share-button click-share"`
`class3="IN-widget" /* class cannot be manipulated */`

`.click-share { display: inline-block; }`
`.IN-widget { display: inline-block; }`

Sorry if I don't seem to be grasping this! I'm sure it's very simple, but I'm at my wit's end overthinking this, trying different combinations of things. Any feedback is much appreciated :)

Comment: @TCharb sorry, I used a bad example. If you have a pre-made button (for example, a Instagram icon) with a premade-class (perhaps `.In-widget`) then you can add a new **custom** class to it so that it'll be easy to style it in your CSS. (`<btn class="In-widget custom-class></btn>"`, note the space between the premade class and the custom class). Now, you can style that button in the CSS `btn.custom-class { /* Styles */}`